# Do not count moderators in the "Total Reputation" tables on StackExchange

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation-leagues, stackexchange.com

The Stack Exchange reputation league table has a Total Reputation table, which is useful to know how many people can do what. Moderators, however, skew the numbers -- their powers are not affected by their reputation.

I believe it would be more meaningful to split moderators off in their own row on this table. Potentially this number could be clicked upon and show the site's moderation team in their full glory.

Comment: Hm, there are only 3 to 6 mods per site, I don't think that's enough to *skew* the numbers.

Comment: @Kenny In young sites, when there's only 5-8 people in the higher reputation levels, 3-6 is enough.

Comment: @Kenny, Take WebApps. They have 5 users with 3k+ rep. Yay! Does that mean they can close vote stuff? No. Three of them are moderators.

Comment: @radp: well, since they are moderators technically it does mean they can close vote stuff, but I know what you mean ;)

Comment: "The Stack Exchange reputation league table has a Total Reputation table, which is useful to know how many people can do what." Wasn't that already possible with the user list?

Comment: @Simon the entire table doesn't add anything the user list doesn't already provide, by your argument it should be removed altogether :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be more confusing than helpful.  The table gives an overview of the users, which is useful for figuring out more than just what powers users have -- for example, figuring out whether a site is growing and how healthy its user-base is (whether it's dominated by a few on top, or a nice healthy curve).

For specific queries about how many non-moderators have certain powers, I'd just look at the actual list of users on the site.